# Java: Drawing lines Slick LWJGL OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm learning how to use OpenGL and starting to build some experiments around Slick 2D Game library but I'm running into a few problems.

I'm trying to draw simple lines, store them in a array then iterate over that array to render each single line. This is the main class:

```
    ArrayList<Bloco> listaBlocos = new ArrayList<Bloco>();
ArrayList<Linha> listaLinhas = new ArrayList<Linha>();
boolean random = false;

@Override
public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
    listaBlocos = new ArrayList<Bloco>();
    listaLinhas = new ArrayList<Linha>();
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) throws SlickException {
    Input input = gc.getInput();

    if (input.isMousePressed(0))
        listaBlocos.add(new Bloco(input.getMouseX() - 5, input.getMouseY() - 5, 10, new Color(0, 255, 0)));
    if (input.isMousePressed(1))
        listaBlocos.add(new Bloco(input.getMouseX() - 5, input.getMouseY() - 5, 10, new Color(255, 0, 0)));

    if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_A))
        if (random == false)
            random = true;
        else
            random = false;

    if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_S))
        listaLinhas.add(new Linha(input.getMouseX(), input.getMouseY(), 100, 100));

    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D))
        listaLinhas.get(0).drawLine();

    if (!listaBlocos.isEmpty() && random)
        for (Bloco b : listaBlocos)
            b.moveRandom(delta);

}

public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

    for (Linha l : listaLinhas)
        l.drawLine();

    for (Bloco b : listaBlocos)
        b.draw(g);

}
```

And this is the Linha class (it extends Line):

```
public class Linha extends Line {

public Linha(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    super(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}

public void drawLine() {

    GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_LINES);
    GL11.glLineWidth(5.0f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(getX1(), getY1());
    GL11.glVertex2f(getX2(), getY2());
    GL11.glEnd();
}
```

}

This was just for testing, if there's a better way to render a bunch of lines please tell me. The problem is that the lines flash on the screen, they're not always there full color. I've recorded the problem so you can see what's happening http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymO00yb5NVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are seeing oddities in your rendering because you have not limited your FPS.

```
AppGameContainer gameContainer = new AppGameContainer(new Game("My Game"));
gameContainer.setTargetFrameRate(30);
```

Having no limit on your FPS might be causing your `update` method to not be called at regular enough intervals because your game is invoking the `render` method too often.